# Assistance required finishing this question

Tags: python, python-3.x

I managed to sort of complete the first part of this question. But I have no idea on how to finish the second part. I managed to complete the input for x and y.

Exercise 1 
The function takes in input a number x and a list of numbers y, and returns a value as
follows:

• If x is odd, fun_exercise_1 subtract 1 from all the elements of y and then returns
its sum.

• If x is even, fun_exercise_1 multiplies each element of y by 2 and then returns its
sum.

• If x is zero, fun_exercise_1 returns the sum of all the elements in y

```
     def fun_exercise_1(x,y):
print ("enter value for x")

x = float (input ("x:"))
y = []

print ("Enter 4 numbers for a list. Use a negative number to finish")
yy = float(input ("Enter Number:"))

while yy >=0.0 :
     y.append(yy)
     yy = float(input("Next number:"))
```

Comment: Consider using `if ... else ...` conditions on `x` and a `for` loop to iterate through all the elements of `y`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it. Although it doesn't validate if the first argument is an integer or if the second argument is a list. It just expects those in order to run correctly.

```
def test(x, y):
    if x == 0:
        sum = 0
        for i in y:
            sum += i + sum
        return sum
    elif x % 2 == 0:
        sum = 0
        for i in y:
            sum += i * 2
        return sum
    else:
        sum = 0
        for i in y:
            sum += i - 1
        return sum
```

This would be tested by passing an integer and a list as arguments when calling test().

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you wanna do:

```
 def fun_exercise_1(x, y):
  if x ==0:
    return sum(y)
  elif x % 2 == 0:
    y = [(val*2) for val in y]
    return sum(y)
  else:
    y = [(val -1) for val in y]
    return sum(y)


print(fun_exercise_1(3,[4,5,6,7]))
```

Output:

```
18
```